# Saving Array as JSON to a file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
{"Files": [
    {"file_name": "Text_file.txt","path": "to_folder","file_id": "abc12345"},
    {"file_name": "Img.jpg","path": "to_folder","file_id": "abc12346"}
]}
```

I want to save information of file uploads to JSON file using php.

```
//Code: PHP class : Save() 
<?php
class Save
{
private $file = './files/data.json', $jsonstring = null, $jsonarray = array(), $temp = array(), $data = array();

public function __construct()
{
    $this->init();
}

private function init()
{
    if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
        touch($this->file);
        $this->read();
    } else {
        $this->read();
    }
}

private function read()
{
    $this->jsonstring = file_get_contents($this->file);
    $this->jsonarray = empty($this->jsonstring) ? array() : json_decode($this->jsonstring, true);
    $this->temp = (object) $this->jsonarray;
}

private function write($data, $collection = false)
{
    if ($collection) {
        if (empty($this->jsonarray) || $this->jsonarray == null && $this->jsonarray[$collection] == null) {
            unset($this->jsonarray);
            $this->jsonarray = array();
            $this->jsonarray[$collection] = array();
            array_push($this->jsonarray[$collection], $data);
            $this->jsonarray = json_encode($this->jsonarray);
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->jsonarray);
            return 1;
        } elseif (property_exists($this->temp, $collection)) {
            // $this->jsonarray[$collection] = array_values($this->jsonarray[$collection]);
            array_push($this->jsonarray[$collection], $data);
            $this->jsonarray = json_encode($this->jsonarray);
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->jsonarray);
            return 2;
        } elseif (!property_exists($this->temp, $collection)) {
            $this->jsonarray[$collection] = array();
            array_push($this->jsonarray[$collection], $data);
            $this->jsonarray = json_encode($this->jsonarray);
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->jsonarray);
            return 3;
        }
    } else {
        if (empty($this->jsonarray) || $this->jsonarray == null) {
            unset($this->jsonarray);
            $this->jsonarray = array();
            array_push($this->jsonarray, $data);
            $this->jsonarray = json_encode($this->jsonarray);
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->jsonarray);
            return 4;
        } else {
            $this->jsonarray = array_values($this->jsonarray);
            array_push($this->jsonarray, $data);
            $this->jsonarray = json_encode($this->jsonarray);
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->jsonarray);
            return 5;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function push($data, $collection = false)
{
    if (is_array($data)) {
        $a =$this->write($data, $collection);
        if ($a) {
            return $a;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($collection = false)
{
    if ($collection) {
        return json_encode($this->jsonarray[$collection]);
    }
    return json_encode($this->jsonarray);
}
}
```

Now Problem is when I upload a single file then it will work fine for 3-6 times then again it resets the JSON file because of null or error in JSON format. & when I Upload 30 files together sending each file automatically.  JS code `[...files].forEach(upload(file))` it behaves oddly. Here is the callback from write function[image: callback]
Update JS:

```
function handelSelect(e) {
    let files;
    if (e.type == 'drop') {
         files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
     } else {
          files = e.target.files;
     }
     if (files.length > 0) handleFiles(files);
 }
//handelFiles(files) send files using ajax(single request).
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Something's missing here. You show some PHP code that will have `Undefined Variable` issues, then ask a question about a very small piece of JavaScript.

Comment: if one request read one version of the file, then another writes to it, then the previous write is overwritten, or worse. try LOCK_EX for file_put_contents, or better, dont store in json use a db

Comment: Let Me Update the code

Answer (score 0):

After examining the execution time i came to conclusion:
Ajax Sending request way faster then PHP can write in file;
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
Benchmark below:

file_put_contents() for 1,000,000 writes - average of 3 benchmarks:

- real 0m3.932s
- user 0m2.487s
- sys 0m1.437s

fopen() fwrite() for 1,000,000 writes, fclose() -  average of 3 benchmarks:

- real 0m2.265s
- user 0m1.819s
- sys 0m0.445s

so I delayed the request in javascript.

```
Object.keys(files).forEach((file) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        uploadFile(files[file], file);
    }, file*2500);
});
```

If anyone has a better solution please share.